# Xamarin.Forms call async method ZXing OnScanResult

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a method like so:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnScanResultAsync(Result result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Customer has been updated.", "OK");



        }
```

and I am trying to call it from my ZXing's

```
<zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="BarcodeScanView" IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="200" OnScanResult="OnScanResultAsync" />
```

But when I try to run my app I get this error:

> Error: Position 8:96. EventHandler "OnScanResultAsync" with correct
>   signature not found in type "Sales.ScannerPage" (Sales)

on my .xaml file

What am I doing wrong and how do I correct it? It was working before I added the DisplayAlert and my method got changed to an async method.

I changed my method to async void, but now I get a warning saying async method should not return void....What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

`OnScanResult` returns a void

```
public async void OnScanResultAsync(Result result)
```

Comment: Not working at all....I do get a warning saying my async method should not return void.